# Does SSH rekeying take place in the encrypted tunnel or outside of it

Tags: ssh, openssh

When an SSH session is rekeyed, does the new key exchange take place within the existing encrypted channel, or does it take place outside of the existing encrypted channel?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Key re-exchange is performed using whatever encryption was in effect    when the exchange was started**

[rfc4253](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc4253.txt)

> 9. Key Re-Exchange
>
>    Key re-exchange is started by sending an SSH_MSG_KEXINIT packet
>      when    not already doing a key exchange (as described in Section
>      7.1).  When    this message is received, a party MUST respond with its own    SSH_MSG_KEXINIT message, except when the received
>      SSH_MSG_KEXINIT    already was a reply.  Either party MAY initiate the
>      re-exchange, but    roles MUST NOT be changed (i.e., the server
>      remains the server, and    the client remains the client).
>
>    Key re-exchange is performed using whatever encryption was in
>      effect    when the exchange was started. Encryption, compression, and
>      MAC    methods are not changed before a new SSH_MSG_NEWKEYS is sent
>      after    the key exchange (as in the initial key exchange). 
>      Re-exchange is    processed identically to the initial key exchange,
>      except for the    session identifier that will remain unchanged.  It
>      is permissible to    change some or all of the algorithms during the
>      re-exchange.  Host    keys can also change.  All keys and
>      initialization vectors are    recomputed after the exchange. 
>      Compression and encryption contexts    are reset.
>
>    It is RECOMMENDED that the keys be changed after each gigabyte of
>      transmitted data or after each hour of connection time, whichever
>      comes sooner.  However, since the re-exchange is a public key
>      operation, it requires a fair amount of processing power and should
>      not be performed too often.
>
>    More application data may be sent after the SSH_MSG_NEWKEYS packet 
>      has been sent; key exchange does not affect the protocols that lie
>      above the SSH transport layer.

Comment: Thank you, but I think I am trying to find an answer to a slightly different question than the one addressed in that RFC.  What I'm trying to determine is whether the new key exchange is encrypted.  In other words, is the new key exchange taking place in the existing encrypted session such that an attacker would not be able to even see that new key exchange unless they had obtained the existing ephemeral symmetric key for the SSH session?  Thank you.

Comment: as I highlighted in the very first line of my post "Key re-exchange is performed using whatever encryption was in effect when the exchange was started" ... so yes, they key re-exchange is entirely encrypted